# What is the "best" package for chemical reaction typing?

Tags: symbols, packages, chemfig, chemistry

I've been trying to insert chemical reactions in my latex document and from what I've seen there are many different related packages for the same purpose. I would like to know what is the easiest to use package of that type which however covers the needs of typing all kinds of chemical reactions (organic compounds etc). Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are indeed several packages for writing chemical reactions in LATEX, but they are not fully equivalent to each other, as they were created for different needs.

To write simple reactions, "chemformula" and "mhchem" are the most suitable.

If you need to do REDOX-type reactions or draw atomic orbitals, use "Chemmacros" .

If you want to create organic molecules and reaction mechanisms, use "chemfig".

The "best" chemistry package for LATEX is the one that does what you need.

The reaction below was done with "chemfig" + "chemmacros"

[image]